# Request to join tables in argis with the option returnGeometry

Tags: join, return, geometry, arcgis

I have joined table in ArcGIS, when I do a query to get the data with the option returnGeometry = true, then the query returns an error "Unable to complete operation." If returnGeometry put in false, the query works correctly.

Has anyone encountered this problem and how to solve it?

Also, if you make a request with "return Ids Only", and further on the download link to go to the feature, I get the error "Invalid or missing input parameters."

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that in the join table field name matching with the field containing the OID.